# SAP Script Recording and Playback : Copy Paste events are not recorded as part of script

Tags: vbscript, sap-gui

While using the script recording and playback feature of SAP GUI Client, I have noticed that Cut/Copy/Paste operations performed by either key press (Ctrl + X, Ctrl + C, Ctrl + V) or from the context menu does not leave a trace in the script generated.

Is there a way to enable these operations as part of script or any workaround to make these events part of recorded script?

Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The answer is "No" but I can't find how to extend the answer so I prefer to not create an answer only for that. Do you want to extend your question to how to copy text from SAP GUI into the clipboard or how to paste the clipboard into SAP GUI? In that case, please generalize the question and its title.

Comment: @SandraRossi Thanks for the prompt response. The copy or paste events are still working, its just that we need to know the exact location in the script where these events occurred. Is there a way to modify script to have those events as well.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is: take a notebook and write when you do you copy/paste actions.
I have done this when recording scripts and it helps me to know where I have done this type actions when analyzing the code.

Also, you can use a screen recorder to complete the formula.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the response. We actually have to automate that process to recognize the cut/copy/paste events in SAP scripts. Any thoughts on same?